# How to set Accelerometer Sensor RAnge up to 8g on Android devices

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors, smartphone

The Accelerometer Sensor is set to a Range of 2 - 4 g on most devices.
There is no option to turn it up to 8 or 16 G, which my sensor and most others are capable of.
I found some Information but cant get any further how to achieve this.

I have the LIS3DSH Sensor in my Xiaomi Device.

There is a manual which states that in the configuration hal file you can set

```
#define SENSOR_ACC_LABEL “LSM303DLHC 3-axis Accelerometer“
#define SENSOR_ACC_INCLUDE_FILE_NAME “lsm303dlhc.h“
#define SENSOR_DATANAME_ACCELEROMETER LSM303DLHC_ACC_DEV_NAME
#define ACCEL_DELAY_FILE_NAME “pollrate_ms“
#define ACCEL_ENABLE_FILE_NAME “enable_device”
#define ACCEL_RANGE_FILE_NAME “range”
#define ACCEL_MAX_RANGE 16*GRAVITY_EARTH
#define ACCEL_MAX_ODR 400
#define ACCEL_POWER_CONSUMPTION 0.033f
#define ACCEL_DEFAULT_FULLSCALE 4
```

But i have no idea how to do this.

[Hal Document](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/application_note/DM00063297.pdf)
In this Document on page 10 there is pointed out a way.
But i dont know how to go on.
Where do i get this source files, or are they already on my device?
Do i have to recompile the whole Android installation or only the sensor hal files?
Im really no ecpert in Android OS Programming but need to solve this.

Furthermore i found one [discussion on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25280924/android-accelerometer-full-range/30332888#30332888) but no progress in solving it.

Im glad for any information.

Ps. To differentiate a bit from the original post, one could also see a point of this question.
How to get the source code for the android sensor HAL and how to recompile it and get it going on the device?

Cheers

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android accelerometer full range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25280924/android-accelerometer-full-range)

Comment: Its meant as an add on to the mentioned discussion, not a duplicate, im also referring to it in the post...

Comment: In that case, you may want to update your question to explain **why** it's not a duplicate, because aside from the fact that you're adding more detail, it reads like a duplicate.  Frankly, it's better-written and better-researched than the original, but still a duplicate.  Just one guy's opinion.  That's why it takes multiple votes to close it out.

Comment: Because it stayed unsolved, since i commented there to get the discussion going again, i was adviced, since it doesnt solve the problem to open a new question. Thats what i did.