# Android Wear accelerometer giving only +- 2g

Tags: java, android, accelerometer, wear-os

Here is my problem: I'm using android wear (sony smart watch3) accelerometer typical way:

```
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    senAccelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, senAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);



@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    switch (sensorEvent.sensor.getType()) {

       case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
            Log.d("swing", "onSensorChanged:" + senAccelerometer.getVersion());
            calculateSensorFrequency(System.currentTimeMillis());
            x = sensorEvent.values[0];
            y = sensorEvent.values[1];
            z = sensorEvent.values[2];
            .
            .
            .
       break;
}
```

In `onSensorChange` method i'm getting only +- 2g reads despite the fact that `Sensor.getMaximumRange()` is giving 16g (156.96 m/s*s). Is there any way to calibrate accelerometer or is this a bug? Any help will be appreciated. Thx

P.S. I was trying to find detailed specyfication of hardware accelerometer module range in google using `Sensor.getVendor` method but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sony Smartwatch 3 has a EM7180 Sensor Fusion Platform (http://www.emmicroelectronic.com/products/sensor-fusion-sensor-interface/sensor-fusion/em7180sfp) built in with a Bosch BMX055 (https://www.bosch-sensortec.com/bst/products/all_products/bmx055) that has an accelerometer, gyroscope and magnetometer. It has several Acceleration ranges ±2g/±4g/±8g/±16g. But mine only reads in the range +/- 2g, too.

Comment: It is very helpful what you said. I'm curious is there a way to unlock those acceleration ranges to enable for example ±8g?

Comment: In the Api there does not seem to be a way to unlock a higher range. But as described (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25280924/android-accelerometer-full-range) the range seems to be device dependant and can only be changed in the Hardware Abstraction Layer in the configuration.h and therefore you have to root the watch. I have tested it now with a second Sony Smartwatch 3 and it has the same range of +/- 2g.